# Why was the state parameter removed from WebServerClient:RequestUserAuthorization in version 4.0.1.12097

Tags: facebook, dotnetopenauth

I have been using DotNetOpenAuth v3.5.0.10357 for about a year now and finally decided to upgrade to v4.0.1.12097. In doing so, I noticed the RequestUserAuthorization method no longer accepts a *state* parameter.

```
//v3.5.0.10357
WebServerClient:RequestUserAuthorization(IEnumerable<string> scope = null, string state = null, Uri returnTo = null);

//v4.0.1.12097
WebServerClient:RequestUserAuthorization(IEnumerable<string> scope = null, Uri returnTo = null);
```

[Facebook documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/), mentions this helps guard against Cross-site Request Forgery. What was the reasoning for the removal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a bit more digging I found out why it was removed. DotNetOpenAuth does state checking internally (***EndUserAuthorizationRequest.ClientState***), leaving one less thing for us to worry about. Nicely done!

Comment: Correct.  I'm glad that our purposes for that variable coincide!